# Cascading onchange calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have list of materials and rate for each material. When user enters quantity for a material, onchange event triggers and calculates material cost as rate*quantity. This I am able to do. I want the sum of all material cost also. I can do that by adding another javascript function in onchange as onchange="mymultiply(100, 'rate_1','quantity_1');mysummation('cost_1','cost_2',...,'sum_cost')". But how to cascade it?

I want a javascript function to trigger when readonly value (cost_1/cost_2 etc) is changed by onchange in quantity_1/quantity_2 etc. onchange works on user input only. Is there a workaround.

So the sample form looks like this.

```
<table>
<tr><th>material</th><th>rate</th><th>quantity</th><th>cost</th></tr>
<tr>
  <td>Material 1</td>
  <td><input type='text' id='rate_1' readonly='true' value='100' /></td>
  <td><input type='text' id='quantity_1' onchange="mymultiply('rate_1','quantity_1','cost_1');" /></td>
  <td><input type='text' id='cost_1' readonly='true' onchange="mysummation('cost_1','cost_2','cost_3','sum_cost');" /></td>
</tr>
<tr> Row 2 data</tr>
<tr> Row 3 data</tr>
</table>

<input type='text' id='sum_cost' readonly='true' />
```

Javascript looks something like this...

```
function mymultiply(rate, quantity, cost){
  document.getElementById(cost).value=document.getElementById(quantity).value*document.getElementById(rate).value;
}

function mysummation(cost_1, cost_2, cost_3, sum){
  document.getElementById(sum).value=document.getElementById(cost_1).value+document.getElementById(cost_2).value+document.getElementById(cost_3).value;
}
```

Comment: where is your javacsript?

Comment: what is cost_1,cost_2...?

Comment: cost will be rate*quantity. In above case, cost_1 input element will contain quantity_1*100. similarly cost_2 etc.

Comment: onchange event occurs only when user has entered something. Question is more about how to trigger a javascript function (mysummation) when value in readonly input is changed by some other javascript function(mymultiply).

Comment: sum_cost will be total cost by adding all costs. Thus sum_cost=cost_1+cost_2+cost_3.

Comment: cost will be rate*quantity? quantity user will give? where will the rate available?

Comment: I had given a very simplified example. I am editing the example if u say

Comment: rates will be available to user in readonly input as rate_1, rate_2...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it

Script

```
    <script>

    function mymultiply(quantity){
       var rate1=document.getElementById('rate_1').value;
       document.getElementById('cost_1').value= parseInt(quantity)*parseInt(rate1);
       document.getElementById('cost_2').value= parseInt(quantity)*200;
       document.getElementById('cost_3').value= parseInt(quantity)*300;
       document.getElementById('sum_cost').value= parseInt(document.getElementById('cost_1').value)+parseInt(document.getElementById('cost_2').value)+parseInt(document.getElementById('cost_3').value);
    }

    </script>
```

HTML

```
    <table>
    <tr><th>material</th><th>rate</th><th>quantity</th><th>cost1</th><th>cost2</th><th>cost3</th></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Material 1</td>
      <td><input type='text' id='rate_1' readonly='true' value='100' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='quantity_1' onKeyUp="mymultiply(this.value);" /></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='cost_1' readonly='true' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='cost_2' readonly='true' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='cost_3' readonly='true' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> Row 2 data</tr>
    <tr> Row 3 data</tr>
    </table>

    Totla Value<input type='text' id='sum_cost' readonly='true' />
```

I think you want to trigger one function from another function Try this

```
$(selector).trigger("change");
```

or

while u calling its

```
 function mymultiply(rate, quantity, cost){
   mysummation('100', '200', '300', '600');//call another function also
 }
```

Comment: i know this will work fine. I have just posted the above question as a n example. It can be solved in number of ways including the one you posted. I want to know, is it possible to cascade it. To be precise, when user enters quantity_1, javascript function mymultiply triggers inside element quantity_1. mymultiply func. changes value inside cost_1 element. javascript function mysummation get triggers automatically when cost_1 changes. Above is just an example. Problem is how to cascade or have chain reaction?

Comment: user can change cost_1 value?

Comment: I think $(selector).trigger("change"); will solve my problem. Can u be more specific as I am new to jquery

Comment: shall I give one sample? then u can proceed with yur original one?

Comment: so i did something like this $("#cost_1").change(function(){$(this).trigger("summation_2");}); I know I may be doing smthg wrong here.

Comment: yup, If i know the requirement. I can help u. But I couldn't get. Itsk u just try. If u not getting answer. U make psd file and give it me:)